# PARI でk 乗根を求めるには？

Tags: ruby, pari

Ruby での

```
(0..(n ** (1.0 / k)).to_i).each{|i| ... }
```

の計算をPARI で行おうとしています。
k 乗したらn になるあたりの**整数**まで計算させたいのですが、

```
for (i=0, sqrtint(n),
for (i=0, sqrtint(sqrtint(n) + 1),
```

のようなコードしか思い浮かびません。
この方法では、一般のk のときではうまくいきません。
一般のk でもうまくいく方法を教えてください。

P.S.

```
for (i=0, sqrtint(n),
for (i=0, sqrtint(sqrtint(n) + 1),
```

を例えば、

```
for (i=0, n^(1.0/2)の整数部分,
for (i=0, n^(1.0/4)の整数部分,
```

みたいなコードにしたいのですが、どうすればいいですか？

私が直面している問題のコードです。
(n+1)^(1.0/2) にかえると動かなくなります。

```
{a(n)=local(CF=1+x*O(x^n), M=sqrtint(n+1)); for(k=0, M, CF=1/(1-x^((M-k+1)^2)*CF)); polcoeff(CF, n, x)}
for(n=0, 55, print1(a(n), ", "))
```

こんなエラーが出ます。

```
  ***   at top-level: for(n=0,55,print1(a(n),", "))
  ***                                   ^-----------
  ***   in function a: ...0/2));for(k=0,M,CF=1/(1-x^((M-k+1)^2)*CF));po
  ***                                              ^--------------------
  *** _^_: domain error in gpow [irrational exponent]: valuation != 0
  ***   Break loop: type 'break' to go back to GP prompt
```

ちなみにM=5 にするとうまく動くが、M=5.1 とすると上記と似たエラーが出ることから、M は**整数**でないとだめみたいです。

Comment: PARI/GP では、for loop の開始値が整数の場合はループ変数は整数として扱われます(切り捨て)。例えば、`for(i=0,n^(1.0/2),print(type(i)))` と `for(i=0.0,n^(1.0/2),print(type(i)))` を実行してみて下さい。

Comment: ＠metropolis: 最初そのような場合をためしてうまくいったのですが、追記のコードはうまくいかないみたいです。

Comment: となると、`M=round((n+1)^(1.0/2))` とするしかなさそうですね。

Comment: ＠metropolis: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました。